# boto3 client NoRegionError: You must specify a region error only sometimes

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-kms

I have a boto3 client :

```
boto3.client('kms')
```

But it happens on new machines, They open and close dynamically.

```
    if endpoint is None:
        if region_name is None:
            # Raise a more specific error message that will give
            # better guidance to the user what needs to happen.
            raise NoRegionError()
```

Why is this happening? and why only part of the time?

Comment: Because boto3 client can't find AWS profile from set of default credentials method  : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html.

Answer (score 676, accepted):

One way or another you must tell boto3 in which region you wish the `kms` client to be created.  This could be done explicitly using the `region_name` parameter as in:

```py
kms = boto3.client('kms', region_name='us-west-2')
```

or you can have a default region associated with your profile in your `~/.aws/config` file as in:

```
[default]
region=us-west-2
```

or you can use an environment variable as in:

```
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2
```

but you do need to tell boto3 which region to use.

Comment: How do I know myself which region to use?

Comment: If you are trying to access existing resources choose the region in which those resources exist.  If you are going to create new resources, most people choose a region which is closest to them geographically for faster response times.  Not all regions support the same set of services so if you need a particular service make sure you choose a region that supports it.

Comment: I guess my question is: how do I know which region I have already chosen?  I suppose it must be in the AWS UI somewhere...

Comment: To find out which regions provide which services:
Amazon Web Services Region Table https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regional-product-services/

Comment: do you know why "export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2" or ~/.aws/config file not working

Comment: I was looking for this answer in regard to SNS. Worked as well.

Comment: works as well with `boto3.resource('service_name', region_name='us-west-2')`

Comment: I wish boto3 could just use the region of the ec2 instance that's running the code.

Comment: Yeah I have my AWS_DEFAULT_REGION set and still no workey

Comment: Why is it not finding my creds even though I input them exactly as they should be?

Comment: Setting a default region in ./aws/config did not solve the issue for me. I had to edit the file directly, adding region name parameter:

`boto3.client('elbv2')` to `boto3.client('elbv2', region_name='us-east-1')`

Comment: @SelçukCihan I agree but you could also do that relatively easily: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73442662/9792594

Answer (score 33):

```
os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = 'your_region_name'
```

In my case sensitivity mattered.

Answer (score 15):

you can also set environment variables in the script itself, rather than passing region_name parameter

`os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = 'your_region_name'`

case sensitivity may matter.

Comment: `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` is case sensitive.

Comment: It should be: `os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = 'us-east-1'`  (upper case)

Answer (score 11):

For Python 2 I have found that the boto3 library does not source the region from the `~/.aws/config` if the region is defined in a different profile to default.
So you have to define it in the session creation.

```py
session = boto3.Session(
    profile_name='NotDefault',
    region_name='ap-southeast-2'
)

print(session.available_profiles)

client = session.client(
    'ec2'
)
```

Where my `~/.aws/config` file looks like this:

```
[default]
region=ap-southeast-2

[NotDefault]
region=ap-southeast-2
```

I do this because I use different profiles for different logins to AWS, Personal and Work.

Answer (score 9):

```js
regions = [
            'eu-north-1', 'ap-south-1', 'eu-west-3', 'eu-west-2',
            'eu-west-1', 'ap-northeast-3', 'ap-northeast-2'
            'ap-northeast-1', 'sa-east-1', 'ca-central-1', 
            'ap-southeast-2', 'eu-central-1', 'us-east-1', 'us-east-2',
            'us-west-1', 'us-west-2']
for r in regions:
   kms = boto3.client('kms', region_name= r)
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using lambdas, then you would likely want to use the region the lambda is deployed in.
You can use the following

```
import boto3
import json
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    region = os.environ['AWS_REGION']
    print('Lambda region: ', region)
    kms = boto3.client('kms', region_name=region)
```

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you can run the following (aws cli)

```
aws configure --profile $PROFILE_NAME
```

it'll prompt you for the region.

notice in `~/.aws/config` it's:

```
[default]
region = ap-southeast-1
output = json

[profile prod]
region = ap-southeast-1
output = json
```

[**profile *profile name***] in the square brackets

Answer (score 4):

I believe, by default, boto picks the region which is set in aws cli. You can run command #aws configure and press enter (it shows what creds you have set in aws cli with region)twice to confirm your region.

Answer (score 3):

For those using CloudFormation template. You can set `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` environment variable using UserData and `AWS::Region`. For example,

```
MyInstance1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance                
    Properties:                           
        ImageId: ami-04b9e92b5572fa0d1 #ubuntu
        InstanceType: t2.micro
        UserData: 
            Fn::Base64: !Sub |
                    #!/bin/bash -x

                    echo "export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${AWS::Region}" >> /etc/profile
```

Answer (score 3):

you could always set it to the same region that the EC2 is in if you like. This is with bash but you could easily reproduce this in python:

```bash
EC2_AVAIL_ZONE=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone)
EC2_REGION="`echo $EC2_AVAIL_ZONE | sed -e 's:\([0-9][0-9]*\)[a-z]*\$:\\1:'`"
# if unset, set it:
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION:-$EC2_REGION}"
```

python:

```py
import os
import re
from subprocess import check_output

EC2_AVAIL_ZONE = check_output(["curl", "-s", "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone"]).decode().strip()
EC2_REGION = re.sub(r"^(\w{2}-\w{3,10}-[0-9][0-9]*)[a-z]*$", r"\1", EC2_AVAIL_ZONE)
# if unset, set it:
os.environ["AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"] = os.getenv("AWS_DEFAULT_REGION", EC2_REGION)
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you are using Linux, an easy way is that you can create the `config` file (You should name it  `config` without any extension) at `~/.aws` (if `.aws` directory does not exist create it at user home `~` ) and in that `config` file add a region just like this.

```js
[default]
region=whatever-aws-region
```

Answer (score 1):

We have the configured regions stored in our ~/.aws/config file.  Here is a pure python way of reading the correct region from this file based on the profile name:

```
def get_aws_region(profile_name: str) -> str:
  config = configparser.ConfigParser()
  config.read(f"{os.environ['HOME']}/.aws/config")
  profile_section = config[f"profile {profile_name}"]
  return profile_section["region"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use AWS Lambda your code will work while you deploy it,
because the Lambda is deployed in a specific region.