# BOTO3 using Python to fetch information of a list of EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to compile information from a list of **EC2s** that I have on a **.csv** using **Python + Boto3**.

This **.csv** contains the Private **IPs** of those instances. The following command returns everything that I need:

```
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --filters Name=addresses.private-ip-address,Values="<PRIVATE IP>" --region <MY REGION>
```

So I've decided to use **Boto3** to do something similar.

But my code isn't returning the information inside the dictionary because I cannot specify the **Region** inside the code.

The documentation allows me to specify the **Availability Zone**, but it won't just work.

```
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
describe_network_interfaces = ec2.describe_network_interfaces(
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'addresses.private-ip-address',
            'Values': [
                '<PRIVATE IP>'
            ],
            'Name': 'availability-zone',
            'Values': [
                '<REGION>'
            ]
        }
    ],
    MaxResults=123
)
print(describe_network_interfaces)
```

☝️ This returns me this

```
{'NetworkInterfaces': [], 'ResponseMetadata': { <LOTS OF METADATA> }}
```

I believe it is not working because I can't specify the **Region** with `describe_network_interfaces` of **Boto3**. But I can do it with the **AWS CLI** command.

Any suggestions?

**OBS:** popen is not a good idea for this current project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [boto3 client NoRegionError: You must specify a region error only sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40377662/boto3-client-noregionerror-you-must-specify-a-region-error-only-sometimes)

Comment: You can specify region when you create the client. region_name='us-west-2'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the region at the client level with something like:

```
my_region = "us-east-1"
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=my_region)
```

This worked in my environment successfully to get information about systems running in another region.

Comment: That worked. :)
Although I need to specify the Availability Zone.

Comment: Add a filter on `availability-zone`.