# how to set env variable in conda and use it in ansible

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ansible, conda

I am debugging this ansible call in a shell script (I am a complete beginner in ansible)

```
source /path/.conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
      conda activate my_ansible && \
      AWS_REGION=us-east-1 \
      AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE=acredsfile \
      ansible-playbook /path/ansible/init.yml \
      -e s3_bucket=${S3_BUCKET}
```

the ansible task gives me a region not found error

```
File "/path/.conda/envs/my_ansible/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/regions.py", line 260, in _endpoint_for_partition
    raise NoRegionError()
botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.
```

I think the way the aws region env is being set is correct but apparently not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [boto3 client NoRegionError: You must specify a region error only sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40377662/boto3-client-noregionerror-you-must-specify-a-region-error-only-sometimes)

Comment: @sytech not quite although it is similar. Thanks for the link.