# How to use S3 in China?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a Python app that uses boto3 to list & read objects from AWS S3 buckets:

```py
session = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id=XYZ, aws_secret_access_key=ABC)
client = session.resource('s3').meta.client
listing = client.list_objects(…)
```

The app works great except for buckets in the China region, where it blows up with `The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records` (the access key & secret are correct).

I googled up something about providing special ARNs / URLs for AWS in China, [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/organizations.html#client) and [here](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/aws/latest/userguide/endpoints-arns.html#cnnorth_region). But what do I do in practice, concretely?

**If the bucket is in China, how do I initialize the boto3 client so that the rest of my code works as normal?**

Comment: e.g. use boto3.client instead of a session and pass it a config with the region: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html ...or pass the region directly to the client like in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40377889/12693728

Comment: e.g. it seems you can pass the region_name to the session too ( https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html) like this: boto3.session.Session(..., region_name="cn-north-1")